# Free WiFi in Tokyo metro

Tags: trains, tokyo, wifi

[This November 2014 article](http://www.huffingtonpost.jp/2014/11/25/tokyo-subway-wifi_n_6222006.html) claims that from December 2014 [Tokyo Metro](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Tokyo#By_train_and_subway) trains would have free WiFi.

Has it become a reality?
If yes, what are the modalities for using it?

Answer (score 8):

Thanks @pnuts for the link that contains the information I was looking for:

> Step 1: Select the “Metro_Free_Wi-Fi” or “Toei_Subway_Free_Wi-Fi” SSID
>   on your laptop or smart device.
>
> Step 2: Launch your web browser.
>
> Step 3: Follow the instructions on the screen (you will be required to
>   register your email address), and you will be connected to the
>   internet. You will be able to use the internet for up to 3 hours each
>   time you log in.
>
> By using the “Japan Connected free Wi-Fi” app and registering your
>   details, you do not need to log into each Wi-Fi access point.

WiFi is not available in trains, only in stations.
Actually, only a selection of stations:

[image: Tokyo metro free WiFi map]

Comment: The JR stations also have free Wifi, which you'll cross pretty often :)

Comment: Just to note, ALL Metro and Toei Stations now have Wifi

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer by @nic, you can also use `JR-EAST FREE Wi-Fi` at some JR stations, and `TOBU_Free_Wi-Fi` at some Tobu line stations. This also requires you to register the service using email, for your information.

The official documentation is the following:

- [JR](http://www.jreast.co.jp/e/pdf/free_wifi_02_e.pdf), available at Japanese, English, Korean, and Simplified and Traditional Chinese.
- [Tobu](http://www.tobu.co.jp/foreign/pdf/FreeWifi.pdf), available at Japanese, English, Korean, Thai, and Simplified and Traditional Chinese.

Also, you can see a list of available free Wi-Fi beyond the stations, including airport and bus station and some major cafe like Starbucks [here](https://www.gotokyo.org/en/tourists/info/wifi.html).

Comment: You may wish to note that Starbucks WiFi requires sign up from a web browser BEFORE you go the first time. Also that thinks like Japan Tourist WiFi are also possible to use (17000+ spots around the country).

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder Well, now you can connect to Starbucks Wi-Fi using social accounts like Twitter or Facebook. As to other choices it gets astray from what OP was asking, which focuses on metro, so I didn't list them all. But now I found the list is available in English and thus I updated it.

Comment: Oooh they changed it. +1 Good to know. I have a contract for NTT Spot so I haven't used Starbucks WiFi in ages (Starbucks offer NTT Spot connections as well). Good to see they are starting to open up to not having to register for everything.